# D3 highlight selected state

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, onclick

I have two `svg`s. One is a map of the US by state, and one is a scatter plot of those states.

My goal is to implement a highlight function, so if the user clicks a state one one of the `svg`s, the state changes (darker, etc.) on both `svg`s.

Currently I have one svg set up as below, with a highlight function. However, on click, the console reports that `TypeError: d is undefined`. Any thoughts or suggestions?

```
  var states = svg.append("g").append("g")
  .attr("id", "states")
    .selectAll("path")
      .data(states_features)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.properties.urm1200app / d.properties.urm1200); })
      .attr("stroke", "#868686")
      .attr("stroke-width", "1px")
      .attr("opacity", .73)
      .on("click", function(d) { return highlight(d.properties.stateabbr); });

function highlight(abbr) {
    svg.selectAll("#states").attr("opacity", function(p) {
        var opa;
        if (p.properties.stateabbr == abbr){
            opa = 1;
            } else {
            opa = .73; }
            return opa;});
}
```

Comment: Could you add more code ? Perhaps make a jsfiddle so we can test for ourselves :)